# Python: Tornado ioloop killed with no exceptions on KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, windows, tornado, keyboardinterrupt

When I press `^C` when blocking on tornado's `ioloop.start()` in the following program, Python quits immediately and no KeyboardInterrupt (or any other exception) is raised. What is going on and how can I catch `^C`?

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)

    # has no effect
    # tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(lambda:None, 1000).start()

    print 'starting'

    try:
        ioloop.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C pressed'

    finally:
        print 'done'
```

Output:

```
$ /c/Python27x32/python test.py
starting

$
```

Expected output:

```
$ /c/Python27x32/python test.py
starting
^C pressed
done

$
```

I'm running:

- Windows 8.0 x64,
- Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
- tornado==3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined that this issue is because I was using the Git Bash console on Windows. When I use the regular command prompt, everything works as expected. I suspect Git Bash is catching ^C and killing the process.

Answer (score -1):

Windows has different signal for console

try
Ctrl + break
or
Ctrl + D